# RDP and win7 without question to connect

Tags: windows-7, rdp

How can I setup the possibility to connect to a domain computer with windows 7 without asking the currently logged in user to confirm that connection?

Answer (score 0):

With which application are you trying to do this? 
External software (Symantec PCAnyhwere, NetOp, TeamViewer, VNC, ....) or using Remote Desktop?

Comment: Since this is asking for a clarification on the question and not actually providing an answer, you should post it as a comment on the question and delete this answer until there is actually a solution to present. Thanks :)

Comment: That's actually what I wanted to do but I can't seem to find a 'comment' option under the originale question...

Comment: Apparently you need to earn 50 reputation points before you can comment on other people's stuff. Answer a few other questions with quality answers and you'll have it in a jiffy, then you can participate on that level. The idea I believe is to keep people from coming here just to "chat" as if it was a discussion board so until you show by playing by the rules (and earn some reputation) you don't get access to the things most likely to be misused due to not understanding the system having just shown up as a guest.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the 'confirm machine identity' the connectee machine's certificate must be trusted on the connecting machine.  If the connecting machine is also on the domain this should not be a problem, otherwise you can 1) run remote desktop as admin 2) connect to the machine 3) inspect the certificate and 4) add it to the trusted store.

If you're referring to the password prompt, you should be able to save that between machines running Vista or higher.